# jQuery Hover Event Affecting Two Different Div's At The Same Time (not nested)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am attempting to write a jQuery function that will display a 1px solid red border around the entire element, not only each individual div (they are not nested, otherwise I could do it with CSS) - See images.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAWqI.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va89e.png)

I want the 1px solid red border to go around the grey header portion, as well as the body of the element where the image appears all at once, when the user hovers anywhere within.

Now, if I call the top portion class "div1" and the bottom class "div2", this is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div1').hover('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

This is my first day using jQuery so I may be completely off. I just need this done for a project.

Also, if there is after all any way to get this done with css (unbeknownst to me) I'd prefer that solution.

Thank you for any help you can give me!

EDIT:
This code is from someone below, but its essentially what I need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.div1').hover(function() {
 $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
 },function() {
 $(this).css('border', '0');
 });
```

});

Except, I don't want this to just happen to 'div1' but also to 'div2' at the same time. How does that get added into this code?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: It's all within a complex WordPress theme. I don't have the html readily available

Comment: How about the output HTML from the template?

Comment: Could you post more of the HTML? It would help to see when each of those divs end.

Answer (score 1):

`div1`, unless it's a custom element, should reference a class or ID instead. And `$.hover()` needs a function to run for when you hover over (and optionally, un-hover) an element. Then you want to use `$.css()` to specify the border change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.div1').hover(function() {
     $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
   },function() {
     $(this).css('border', '0');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">div1</div>
```

A better way to do it though, is to assign a class on hover.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.div1').hover(function() {
         $(this).addClass('border');
       },function() {
         $(this).removeClass('border');
       });
    });
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">div1</div>
```

And an even better way to do it is just use CSS, though just including that for good measure here, not necessarily the answer to your question.

```css
.div1:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="div1">div1</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, its very close. The only issue I am having now is just that div1 and div2 both have to be affected, no matter if they user hovers over div1 or div2 (the events have to occur at the same time)

Comment: @bay_bay no problem. I need to see your code replicating that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` css pseudo selector

```
.div1:hover {
   border : 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason this can't entirely be accomplished in HTML and CSS? When the user hovers over the parent element, the red border is applied. Like so:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.main:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

.header {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="header">Round Stickers</div>
            <div class"content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would, it those divs were nested like yours is. Unfortunately they are not. And that's why I figured i may need jQuery